# Filtering gallery, to remove duplicates (without distinct) in PowerApps

Tags: filter, duplicates, distinct, powerapps

I have prepared gallery, that displays items imported from excel file as a list. User after clicking on certain item is redirected to next screen with details of selected item.
As there is a lot of duplicates, I decided to add another screen, with copy of the gallery, but with the filter that displays only items with name as selected in previous screen - this works fine.
Now I want to get rid of duplicates in main list (that displays all items), so user sees only one name, and after clicking on this (on the next screen) all items with this name are displayed.

I tried with distinct, but without succes. Additionaly as far as I understand, distinct creates new column with duplicates deleted. I want to avoid that, it would require a lot of effort, to rebuild app.
If there is such possibility, I would prefer it to filter out duplicates directly on gallery (so it works similar to filter/search/sort)

```
If(
    dropdown_sort.Selected.Value = "Name of the training";
    SortByColumns(
        Search(
            Filter(
                Table1_2;
                '4. Area of training' = "IT-related" || '4. Area of training' = "IT and BIZ-related"
            );
            search_engine.Text;
            "3_x002e__x0020_Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_training";
            "1_x002e_Name_x0020_and_x0020_surname"
        );
        "3_x002e__x0020_Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_training";
        If(
            sort;
            Ascending;
            Descending
        )
    );
    SortByColumns(
        Search(
            Filter(
                Table1_2;
                '4. Area of training' = "IT-related" || '4. Area of training' = "IT and BIZ-related"
            );
            search_engine.Text;
            "3_x002e__x0020_Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_training";
            "1_x002e_Name_x0020_and_x0020_surname"
        );
        "7_x002e__x0020_Describe_x0020_your_x0020_level_x0020_of_x0020_satisfaction_x0020_after_x0020_the_x0020_training_x002e_";
        If(
            sort;
            Ascending;
            Descending
        )
    )
);
```

I have code above to support simple search engine, sorting (asc/desc), dropdown menu, that determines column to sort. So I think we have to frankenstein another function into it.
Sorry, for the code, as it isn't well optimized. If you have any ideas to clean it up, don't hasiate to mention it.
Thank you.